# Возможно ли создать полностью встраиваемую бинарную библиотеку на C++?

Tags: c++

Эм. Да, я не знаю/придумал, как именно назвать эту "встраиваемость". Речь идет о линковке со статическим объектным файлом или (на крайний случай) с динамической библиотекой.

То есть бинарную библиотеку на C++ (с классами и т.д.), которую можно было бы прилинковать к программе без свистоплясок, сводящих всю библиотеку к тем же сишным структурам, глобальным переменным и функциям.

Пока мне известен только способ, при котором создаются в блоке `extern "C"` глобальные функции-обёртки, вызывающие функции-члены переданных им объектов, в свою очередь полученных при инициализации библиотеки.

/Как здесь: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp /

Это сводит всю библиотеку к совокупности глобальных функций и явно передаваемых им объектов (почти обычных структур с точки зрения внешнего взаимодействия). К тому же, большую библиотеку при таком подходе трудно поддерживать из-за необходимости тщательно следить за списком функций-обёрток.

Собственно, вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать по-другому. В представляемом мною идеальном случае нужно просто прилинковать библиотеку к создаваемой программе и спокойно пользоваться ею, как будто подключены исходники. Возможно ли это?

Или всё же надо делать и распространять набор файлов с исходным кодом для совместной с программой компиляцией?

Comment: dll, so или lib? Всем им не нужны исходники

Comment: @MrBin , в моем случае идея изначально для линукса, .a или .so . А в этом вопросе dll/lib как-то существенно отличаются?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что именно вы назвали "свистоплясками"? Как ни вертитесь, объявления типов, переменных и функций все равно будут делаться через заголовочные файлы.

Comment: @AnT , "свистоплясками" назвал необходимость создавать глобальные функции-обёртки под соглашениями линковки "C" и потерю привычной работы с объектами этой библиотеки просто для того, чтобы избежать декорирование имен компилятором.

Comment: Это называется С-интерфейс. Просто используйте С++ интерфейс (при этом все имена естественно будут декорированными).

Comment: @VTT , <s>как и ожидалось</s> кажется, я что-то пропустил. Что в этом контексте означает слово "интерфейс"?
И что делать с декорированными именами? Исследовать nm'ом после компиляции и по таблице символов составлять документацию/хидеры?

Comment: Под интерфейсом тут понимается набор типов и методов, которые должен будет вызывать пользовательский код. Документация и заголовочные файлы безоговорочно необходимы в любом случае. А вот набор функций оберток совсем не обязателен.

Comment: @VTT , то есть при каждом существенном изменении библиотеки нужно заново вручную проверять все таблицы имен и править либо документацию, описывающую имена вроде _ZN14PhysicalObjectC2ERKS_ (а еще будет весело, если они вдруг будут меняться), либо дополнительные заголовочные файлы, (условно) назначающие этим декорированным именам нормальные. И мне это как-то кажется трудоёмко, ненадёжно ии вообще неправильно?

Comment: Если всё собирается одним компилятором (и библиотека, и приложение), тогда можно просто собрать библиотеку и всё. Если нет, тогда либо C-interface, либо распространение исходников, чтобы люди под себя собирали. Либо же распространение собранных библиотек под наиболее популярные компиляторы. Смотрите как это сделано в Qt.

Comment: Нет, имена в декорируемой форме описывать нигде не надо, заголовочные файлы содержат обычные объявления классов и функций.